# Where can I buy rose petals that are safe for human consumption?

Tags: culinary-uses, jam, flowers

I'd like to make a rose petal jam, which requires roughly 14-16 ounces of rose petals. However, I've been warned to not buy roses from florists, due to potential pesticide issues from roses sold for being displayed, not for eating. Is there any place to get fresh rose petals that are organic and/or pesticide free? My guess would be a farmer's market or the like?

Comment: Since your recipe is in ounces I assume you're in the USA, but can you confirm that? Some people from the UK still cook in Imperial units, and I think I know a UK-based supplier who probably doesn't deliver to the US.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the USA.

Comment: You'll have more problems than safety. You won't be able to get the proper rose (damascena) anyway. Out of the roses you can get, most will have zero aroma, because they are bred for looks :(

Comment: You can look into rose petal herbal products that are packed for consumption. Rose petals meant for brewing herbal tea is also ok. Ideally go for rose buds. They're younger, and have less potential for pesticide exposure.

Answer (score 3):

You can get them [dried and otherwise processed](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_4_4?url=search-alias%3Dgrocery&field-keywords=rose%20petals&sprefix=rose%2Cgrocery%2C444) from Amazon, [rose water](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_10?url=search-alias%3Dgrocery&field-keywords=rose+water&sprefix=rose+water%2Cgrocery%2C275&rh=n%3A16310101%2Ck%3Arose+water) too. Fresh is going to be a greater challenge. I don't know of a better answer than *letting your fingers do the walking* or making friends with a gardener.

Of course, if money is no object there is always an [option](http://www.flowerexplosion.com/by-flower/roses/edible.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try organic markets in your area

Answer (score 0):

This is a crap-shoot, but if you have any gardeners who grow roses in your neighborhood it might be worth it to ask around and see if you could buy or barter for some of their flowers. You could also grow your own.

Alternatively, see if there is an organic florist in your area. Interest in organic goods is increasing in North America, and people are getting into this market.

Comment: Word of caution: organic doesn't mean pesticide-free. It just means that the pesticides used are derived from "natural" sources. Some of those you definitely don't want to be eating.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult. I don't think there is a place at this time. I have made wonderful rose jelly but you will not get the flavor you are looking for if they are not plucked straight away from the rose bush. Wild roses often do not have the fragrance, which is where the flavor will derive from. When you find, it is best to pick in the morning. Pull petals off and snip the white base as it is bitter. Best bet is to find an organic, non-pesticide farmer/gardener or grow yourself.